# eclipse, one classpath for compiling, another for launching

Tags: eclipse, classpath

example:
For logging, my code uses `log4j`. but other jars my code is dependent upon, uses `slf4j` instead. So both jars must be in the build path. Unfortunately, its possible for my code to directly use (depend on) `slf4j` now, either by context-assist, or some other developers changes. I would like any use of slf4j to show up as an error, but my application (and tests) will still need it in the classpath when running.

explanation:
I'd like to find out if this is possible in eclipse. This scenario happens often for me. I'll have a large project, that uses alot of 3rd party libraries. And of course those 3rd party jars have their own dependencies as well. So I have to include all dependencies in the classpath ("build path" in eclipse) for the application and its tests to compile and run (from within eclipse).

But I don't want *my* code to use all of those jars, just the few direct dependencies I've decided upon myself. So if my code accidentally uses a dependency of a dependency, I want it to show up as a compilation error. Ideally, as class not found, but any error would do.

I know I can manually configure the classpath when running outside of eclipse, and even within eclipse I can modify the classpath for a specific class I'm running (in the run configurations), but thats not manageable if you run alot of individual test cases, or have alot of main() classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [access rules](http://www.eclipsezone.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=91952212) to keep your code clean?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your project has enough dependency relationships that you might consider structuring it with OSGi bundles (plug-ins).  Each bundle gets its own classloader and gets to specify what bundles (and optionally what version ranges, etc.) it depends on, what packages it exports, whether it re-exports stuff from its dependencies, etc.

Eclipse itself is structured out of Eclipse plug-ins and fragments, which are just OSGi bundles with an optional tiny bit of additional Eclipse wiring (`plugin.xml`, which is used to declare Eclipse "extension points" and "extensions") attached.  Eclipse thus has fairly good tooling for creating and managing bundles built-in (via the Plug-in Development Environment).  Much of what you find out there may lead you to conflate "OSGi bundle" with "plug-in that extends the Eclipse IDE", but the two concepts are quite separable.

The Eclipse tooling does distinguish rather clearly (and sometimes annoyingly, but in the "helpful medicine" way) between the bundles in your build environment vs. the bundles that a particular run configuration includes.

After a few years of living in OSGi land, the default Java "flat classpath" feels weird and even kind of broken to me, largely because (as you've experienced) it throws all JARs into one giant arena and hopes they can sort of work things out.  The OSGi environment gives me a lot more control over dependency relationships, and as a "side effect" also naturally demands clarification of those relationships.  Between these clear declarations and the tooling's enforcement of them, the project's structure is more obvious to everyone on the team.

> if my code accidentally uses a dependency of a dependency, I want it to show up as a compilation error. Ideally, as class not found, but any error would do.

Put your code in one plug-in, your direct dependencies in other plug-ins, their dependencies in other plug-ins, etc. and declare each plug-in's dependencies.  Eclipse will immediately do exactly what you want.  You won't be offered dependencies' dependencies' contents in autocompletes; you'll get red squiggles and build errors; etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would better be managed with maven, integrated in eclipse with **[m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/)**.

That way, you can only execute part of the maven build lifecycle, and you can manage separate set of dependencies per build steps.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it helps to be more resrictive, I made the team filling out (paper) forms why this jar is needed and what license...

and they did rather type in a few lines of code instead of drag along 20 jars to open a file using only one line of code, or another fancy 'feature'.

Using maven could help for a while, but when you first spot jars having names like nightly-build or snapshot, you will know you're in jar-hell.

conclusion: Choose dependencies well

Answer (score 0):

Would using the slf4j-over-log4j jar be useful?  That allows using slf4j with actual logging going to log4j.